# Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from string SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, ssms

I am Surprised, While i copy and paste `'Mon, 26 Aug 2013 5:32:44 GMT'` in database table field of type `DateTime` in Editable mode it update that cell but while i am Executing query Like

```
declare @Manoj date
Set @Manoj = 'Mon, 26 Aug 2013 5:32:44 GMT'
update NK_News set  PubDate =@Manoj  where ID= 70
```

here `PubDate` is DateTime field

It generate error as `Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string`

Is there any way to find what exactly Query run at Editable Mode in SQL Server Management Studio.

Answer (score 1):

```
Set @Manoj = stuff(replace('Mon, 26 Aug 2013 5:32:44 GMT', ' GMT', ''), 1,5, '')
```

Comment: @Tclausendk I already tested this too but this is also not Working same problem

Comment: @Tclausendk actually it is not able to convert GMT to Server time